# Numerical algorithm to calculate stream of discounted cash flows

Tags: numerics

Is it possible to calculate the flow of cash in each period given a certain fixed net present value with a numerical algorithm?

I would like to be able to apply a certain weighting that can be applied to the cash flows of each period e.g. 90% will be paid back in the last period, 1/(number of periods-1) in all other preceding periods.

For example, parameters could be:
number of periods of the cash flow, discount rate, indexation/inflation, certain weighting that can be applied to the cash flows of each period, etc.

What formula should I start from? Or is there a R/Python/... package that can calculate this for me?

[image]

So I want to calculate the uneven cash flows CF 1-n, which has to be done numerically I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can express the payment in each period as $CF_i = a_i x$ where $x$ is the sum to be paid. You can easily plug x in easily substitute this in the equation and calculate the value of $x$, once you know $x$ you can calculate $CF_i$

To determine $x$ start with

$$ PV = \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{CF_i}{(1+r)^i} = \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{a_i x}{(1+r)^i}$$

and solve

$$ x = \frac{PV}{\sum_{i=0}^n a_i{(1+r)^{-i}}} $$

For your example you have

$$ a_{i} = \left\{\begin{matrix} 1/(10n)&\textrm{if }i \ne n \\
9/10 & \textrm{if } i=n \end{matrix}\right.$$

Comment: Something I forgot to mention, is that I also need to calculate net present value, not just present value. So e.g. in the initial period there is a negative value of e.g. -100, and at the end it is assumed it can be resold for e.g. +95. Or based on some formula that relates the 100 to the 95 which can be complex and dependent on n. But let's assume it's not dependent on n and weights can be give beforehand. All the in between cash flows are dependent on the 100 too, e.g. if they were discounted; they would each equal 1/(number of periods-2) of the initial cashflow.This seems to make it harder?

Comment: Wow, thx! Shouldn't you divide the right hand side by n though, as you get x out of the summation sign from zero to n ? x is the same for each cash flow/period, right? 
In the next step: how do I get the CFi out of the summation sign when solving for CFi in the PV =  formula? PV/summation (1+r)^-i minus all the other CFi 's (but which are also unknown, so ... )?

Comment: Oh no sorry, to calculate CFi you just multiply a_i times x.

Comment: Ach no you are right, there is no index i for x so you can indeed just get it out of the summation from i to n.

Comment: Basically to include the concept of NET present value, a_i can be considered to be either positive or negative. But is the derivation of x still valid then? Now it seems like all a_i sum to one over all periods, but not sure if that is really necessary?

Comment: $a_i$ may add to something different than 1, if you have a distribution $a_i$ and another distribution $b a_i$, the second will give $x/b$ instead of $x$, and $b a_i (x / b) = a_i x$. The only restriction is that the discounted values of $a_i$ must add to something different than zero, in the denominator of the formula for x.

Comment: I see. So in practice I can normalize my weights, with negative ones included, first, and then just apply your formula?


For example:


weights1 = c(0.2, 0.3)

normalize1 = weights1/sum(weights1)  => b is 0.5

weights2 = c(-0.2, 0.2, 0.3)

normalize2 = weights2/sum(weights2) => b is 0.3


> normalize2   


so I use this as the "a" vector with elements a_i
[1] -0.6666667  0.6666667  1.0000000

Comment: Yes, you got it

Comment: I programmed something, and it works very well. The only thing is, sometimes the common factor, x, turns out negative. Which is mathematically correct, but turns all costs into profits and vice verse in order to solve it. Which in reality is not advisable :). So how do I force it to solve for x to be positive for any weight vector? I could of course adjust the weight vector to force x to be positive, but that's not what I want to do. But I guess when I get x < 0 there just isn't an "economically viable" solution given the inputs?

Comment: If you get a negative X it means that you are trying to pay a negative amount for a positive PV, or vice-versa, the formula is working as an anti-fraud for you hehe

Comment: Yes indeed :) . Ok.

Comment: I found that actually the fact if x is positive or negative is independent of the amount of the value of PV (this is always a positive number in my case).

What I noticed is that the weight vector is what determines if the denominator in the x = ... formula is positive or negative. The nominator is always positive.

So that's not really what I want although I get why it works like that. If PV is large enough, it should be able to calculate a series of cash flows that satisfies this PV (and weight factor).

Comment: I guess I could leave one or more a_i as an dependent variable...  . And specify bounds for it? And then maybe I need a numerical algorithm to close in on the solution?

Comment: The problem is that in the current solution, the weight vector in itself must be "economically viable", so that the sign doesn't switch.

But that does not take into account that every year I also save some money by, in my case, terminating a rental contract. The NPV saved I now put as the PV in the formula. But that doesn't influence the sign switching... . But I don't know how to bring the rental info into the weight vector maybe, and solve for NPV = 0. Which may make more sense... .

Comment: Maybe a possible approach is to add to the weight vector specifying the distribution of cash flows for the property +1/n with n =  number of years? As such, you incorporate the information that each year you also save about 1/n of the total NPV that is your input variable and which was calculated beforehand from the known series of cash flows from the rental place?

Comment: Yes this seems to make sense. For a given amount of NPV by giving up the rental contract, you have a positive cashflow each year, distributed over the years by a vector, say v. For this amount of NPV, you want to know the max. price of investment in year zero given a series of cashflows of which the distribution is determined by a vector w. You do v+w for the final vector of weights, called a, used in the formula of Bob.

Comment: Hmmm, no it's not a solution to the problem because
1. The ratio of the weights in vector v to vector w is unknown.
Therefore it's not known how to combine both vectors v and w correctly to construct  vector a. If you just add them, you get weird results.

Comment: Ach nevermind, should just put the NPV value negative of course, then it behaves as expected.